# Динамически отслеживаемые props

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Предположим, есть нечто такое:

```
<div class="parent">
  <my-component :data="someData"/>
</div>
```

MyComponent:

```
<div :class="{'super-class': someData}"></div>
```

В родителе выглядит так:

```
data() {
  return {
    condition: false
  }
},
computed() {
  someData() {
    return condition === true ? true : false;
  }
}
```

В my-component так:

```
props: ['data'],
Other not important logic...
```

Вопрос, собственно, в том, что в родителе в какой-то момент компьютед свойство someData становится true, и надо бы, чтобы это событие влияло на дочерний компонент, но, почему-то, не влияет. Есть мысли, как можно починить?

Comment: в дочернем компоненте переопределите `data` через `computed` либо через `watch`

Comment: Не очень понятно, что вы имеете ввиду. Если смотреть через те же девтулзы, то при изменении переменной в родителе, которая идёт пропом в дочерний, проп в дочернем не видит этих изменений и остаётся со значением, с которым был создан. Я пробовал вешать watch на prop, но из этого ничего не вышло, потому что изменения пропа не происходит.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`computed` свойства также отлично работают и в дочернем компоненте, посмотрите мой пример:

```js
Vue.component('child',{
  props: {
    data: {
      type: Boolean
    }
  },
  template: `<div :class="{'super-class': data}">Text</div>`
});

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      condition: false
    }
  },
  computed: {
    someData() {
      return this.condition;
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    setInterval(() => {
      this.condition = !this.condition;
    }, 1000);
  }
})
```

```css
.super-class {
  font-size: 25px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app" class="parent">
  <child :data="someData"/>
</div>
```

Comment: В общем, это работает. Но мою проблему по какой-то не понятной для меня причине это не решило. Может быть, потому что в компоненте в хуке `created()` там много чего происходит, затрагивающее это всё, но в другом компоненте (кастомный инпут) этот вариант проскочил на ура. Вообще, уже 9 месяцев занимаюсь фронтом на вью, и впервые столкнулся с такой проблемой. В любом случае, спасибо за ответ!

Comment: Еще раз внимательно сравните ваш код и пример, возможно где-то что-то упустили. Смущает строка `return condition === true ? true : false;`, где должно быть `return this.condition === true ? true : false;`, может просто опечатка...

Comment: Да, это просто опечатка. Спасибо. Это абстрактный пример того, что я хотел объяснить. На самом деле компонент сложнее и в `created()` смотрит на объект, который приходит пропом и, исходя из того, что там пришло, рисует кнопку. Я думаю, что как раз в это беда. Буду рефачить его. Так дело не пойдёт.